# Value from generic class to generic base class

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, inheritance, asp.net-web-api2

In WebApi Core, I pass the context to a service collections via AddDataAccess. I really don't understand why the context is null at this line :

```
var res = this.Context.Set<TEntity>().AsEnumerable();
```

Some people will say because there is null in in the parameter in the constructor but to my it's correct. Should be something else.

//In the Stratup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<myConnectionStringContext>
        (options => options.UseSqlServer(_config["ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString"]));
    services.AddDataAccess<myConnectionStringContext>();

    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

//In my personnal package

```
    public static class ServiceCollectionExtentions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddDataAccess<TEntityContext>(this IServiceCollection services) 
            where TEntityContext : DbContext
        {
            RegisterDataAccess<TEntityContext>(services);
            return services;
        }

        private static void RegisterDataAccess<TEntityContext>(IServiceCollection services) 
            where TEntityContext : DbContext
        {
            services.AddTransient(typeof(TEntityContext));
            services.AddTransient(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(GenericEntityRepository<>));
        }
    }

public class EntityBase
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IRepository<TEntity>
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();
}

public class GenericEntityRepository<TEntity> : EntityRepositoryBase<DbContext, TEntity> 
    where TEntity : EntityBase, new()
{
    public GenericEntityRepository() : base(null)
    { }
}

public abstract class EntityRepositoryBase<TContext, TEntity> : RepositoryBase<TContext>, IRepository<TEntity> 
    where TContext : DbContext where TEntity : EntityBase, new()
{
    protected EntityRepositoryBase(TContext context) : base(context)
    { }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return this.Context.Set<TEntity>().AsEnumerable();
    }
}

public abstract class RepositoryBase<TContext> where TContext : DbContext
{
    protected TContext Context { get; private set; }

    protected RepositoryBase( TContext context)
    {
       this.Context = context;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## The Problem

Because you are passing a `null` here:

```
public GenericEntityRepository() : base(null) // <-- passing null
```

This goes to the parent `EntityRepositoryBase`

```
protected EntityRepositoryBase(TContext context) : base(context) // <--(1) context = null
```

Then goes to the parent `RepositoryBase`

```
protected TContext Context { get; private set; } // <--(4) context = null

protected RepositoryBase(TContext context) // <--(2) context = null
{
    this.Context = context; // <--(3) context = null
}
```

So when you call

```
return this.Context.Set<TEntity>().AsEnumerable();

this.Context // <-- this is null
```

## The Solution

You need to change your `GenericEntityRepository` from sending a `null` to sending the `dbContext`

```
public class GenericEntityRepository<TEntity> : EntityRepositoryBase<DbContext, TEntity>
    where TEntity : EntityBase
{
    public GenericEntityRepository(ApplicationDbContext dbContext) : base(dbContext) { }
}
```

Alternatively, you can do this too (preferred):

```
public class GenericEntityRepository<TContext, TEntity> : EntityRepositoryBase<TContext, TEntity>
    where TContext: DbContext, new()
    where TEntity : EntityBase
{
    public GenericEntityRepository() : base(new TContext()) { }
}
```

> Note: With the code you have provided, you could probably do away with  a couple of these generic classes, since they serve no function other than just inheriting unnecessarily.

Comment: You didn't read. I expected this answer but I don't think it's that. And if it's that how pass the DbContext then ?

Comment: @Kris-I I've updated my answer, to show you why it's true.

Comment: Ok understood. But but how create the DBContext then ? (with a new)

Comment: @Kris-I - I updated the answer for you with a couple options. You should also take a look at how you are adding the service, you don't need to use `typeof(xxx)` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection#designing-your-services-for-dependency-injection

Comment: @Kris-I Where is your issue at? `services.AddTransient()` ?

Comment: no no before that, in the inheritance a generic stuff problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151182/discussion-between-kris-i-and-svek).

Comment: @Kris-I You might want to post a new question more specific to your new problem.

Comment: Close to the end (in theory).... the issue is at services.AddTransient()
GenericEntityRepository<TContext, TEntity>' requires 2 type arguments